# n Count the difference between values in two tables

Tags: sql-server

I have Table PREV:

```
Client    Ctg
1          CC
1          OVD
2          CC
3          OVD
```

and table ACT:

```
Client    Ctg
1          OVD
2          CC
4          OVD
```

And i need to count the difference between those two tables for each product (how many clients left the product and how many are new ones)

So the result should be left CC -1 , OVD -1 new ones OVD 1

Those results can be in two different selects

I tried this :

> select count (*) from PREV left join ACT on client = client where
>   cliet is null group by Ctg

but this is not working when one client has more products... :/

Please note that there are thousands of clients and each of them can have up to 5 products (Ctg)

Plus in each month (ACT and PREV are like February/January) are clients which left and clients which are new. In final form i want to count new ones as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the number of records that are in the one table and not the other, do a left/right join between them and count the number of nulls. IE:

```
SELECT a.Ctg, a.Client PrevClient, b.Client ActClient
FROM PREV a
LEFT JOIN ACT b ON a.Client = b.Client AND a.Ctg = b.Ctg
```

So now ActClient will be null where it there is a record in the PREV table that is NOT in the ACT table.  You can then simply get the count by wrapping that SQL in another SQL statement. IE

```
SELECT Ctg, COUNT(*) FROM (
SELECT a.Ctg, a.Client PrevClient, b.Client ActClient
FROM PREV a
LEFT JOIN ACT b ON a.Client = b.Client AND a.Ctg = b.Ctg
) Tmp
WHERE ActClient IS NULL
GROUP BY Ctg
```

So to get the count of the record in ACT that are not in PREV, you can simply use the same query with a RIGHT join. and change the `a.Ctg` to `b.Ctg`

Comment: Thats what i tried... I wrote it in The question, but i cant just compare clients because i have clients that have more than one type of product and i need The counts for every product separately

Comment: I changed the SQL so you group on product.

Comment: I will try it tomorrow at work, thank you for your time.

Comment: Oh so the only thing i had to do was add the second condition to the join (ctg = ctg) ... :/ Thank you

Answer (score 0):

you tried something like this?

```
select a.ctg,a.sum2-b.sum1 from 
(select ctg, count(*) sum2 from prev group by ctg)a,
(select act.ctg ctg, count(*) sum1 from prev join act 
on prev.client=act.client and prev.ctg=act.ctg group by act.ctg)b;
```

Comment: I edited the question, this maybe work when i need just one number - the total difference. But i need difference in each category separately

Answer (score 0):

cte is doing calculation for PREV counts and then comparing with current counts.

```
; with cte
as
( select prev.Ctg, COUNT(ctg) as prevCount
  from PREV
  group by prev.Ctg
)
SELECT ACT.Ctg , COUNT(act.ctg) - cte.prevCount as Difference, COUNT(act.ctg) as CurrentCount, cte.prevCount as PrevCount
from ACT
join cte
on act.Ctg = cte.Ctg
group by ACT.Ctg, cte.prevCount
```

Comment: But when i do it like this i cant recognize how many left and how many are new ones right? I will only know the difference between those two - please see my edited question

Comment: added the counts also to the select list

Comment: I will try it tomorrow at work, thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

basic version:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [ACT] as a 
where not exists (select * from [PREV] as p
where a.Client = p.Client and a.Ctg = p.Ctg)
```

ok, so thet try this one:

```
select  a.Ctg, COUNT(a.Client) as ClientCoutThatAddThatCategory
from ACT as a
left outer join PREV as p
on a.Client=p.Client and a.Ctg=p.Ctg
where p.Client is NULL
group by a.Ctg


select p.Ctg, COUNT(p.Client) as ClientCoutThatLeftThatCategory
from ACT as a
right outer join PREV as p
on a.Client=p.Client and a.Ctg=p.Ctg
where a.Client is NULL
group by p.Ctg
```